# Sum of values in dictionary of bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check the sum of some data stored in a dictionary of bytes (block variable) and I'm getting this weird behavior.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'
```

Here is a snippet.

```
values = block.values()

if sum(values) == data:
    return True
 
else:
    return False
```

The block looks like this:

```
{'V': b'26587\r', 'VS': b'31\r', 'I': b'0\r', 'P': b'0\r', 'CE': b'0\r', 'SOC': b'1000\r', 'TTG': b'-1\r', 'Alarm': b'OFF\r', 'Relay': b'OFF\r', 'AR': b'0\r', 'BMV': b'712 Smart\r', 'FW': b'0408\r', 'MON': b'0\r'}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sum"? Do you want to add the numbers in the bytestrings?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried using 'bytes()' as the starting value but got an error. The error suggested that I used the 'join()' method so I did and got b'26590\r32\r0\r0\r0\r1000\r-1\rOFF\rOFF\r0\r712 Smart\r0408\r0\r'.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I am trying to sum up the data to compare it with a checksum byte (b'\xf1\r')

Comment: @XuDank You're going to have to explain in more detail what you mean to do, then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working with a [BMV-712 Smart](https://www.victronenergy.com/battery-monitors/bmv-712-smart) and their [Protocol FAQ](https://www.victronenergy.com/live/vedirect_protocol:faq#q8how_do_i_calculate_the_text_checksum) says the checksum is calculated by adding all the values together (including the keys and checksum) with the value wrapping at 255.

Turning their pseudo code into Python I get the expected answer for their example:

```py
def create_checksum(msg):
    value = 0x00
    for bite in msg:
        value = (value + bite) % 256
    return value


message = (b'\r\nPID\t0x203\r\nV\t26201\r\nI\t0\r\nP\t0\r\nCE\t0\r\n'
           b'SOC\t1000\r\nTTG\t-1\r\nAlarm\tOFF\r\nRelay\tOFF\r\nAR\t0\r\n'
           b'BMV\t700\r\nFW\t0307\r\nChecksum\t\xd8')
msg1 = create_checksum(message)
print(f"Msg1: Expect 0x0: Got = {hex(msg1)}")
# Msg1: Expect 0x00: Got = 0x0
```

I've taken your data and manually made it one message and added in the checksum values but it is not working:

```py
def create_checksum(msg):
    value = 0x00
    for bite in msg:
        value = (value + bite) % 256
    return value

data_txt2 = (b'\x0dV\t26587\rVS\t31\rI\t0\rP\t0\r'
             b'CE\t0\rSOC\t1000\rTTG\t-1\r'
             b'Alarm\tOFF\rRelay\tOFF\rAR\t0\r'
             b'BMV\t712 Smart\rFW\t0408\rMON\t0\r'
             b'Checksum\t\xf1\r')

msg2 = create_checksum(data_txt2)
print(f"Msg2: Expect 0x0: Got = {hex(msg2)}")
# Msg2: Expect 0x0: Got = 0x4
```

This is giving the wrong answer so I suspect the data you have shared is not quite right.